# Find items from a list starting with the letter a through m

Tags: python, list, search

For example we have a list:

```py
l = ["aqi", "cars", "dosage", "dummy", "maze", "quiz", "sample", "trips", "users", "zoo"]
```

- Assuming the list to be sorted.
- Will have 2 parameters startAt and endAt

  - can be both string or int

The function takes in the list and returns all the elements that start from `a` through `m`

Here's my implementation:

```py
def get_items_between_indexes(
    items: List[str], startAt: Union[str, int], endAt: Union[str, int]
) -> List[str]:
    """
    Get items between two indexes (inclusive).

    Args:
        items (List[Union[str, int]]): The list of items to search.
        startAt (Union[str, int]): The item to start searching from.
        endAt (Union[str, int]): The item to end searching at.

    Returns:
        List[Union[str, int]]: The list of items between the two indexes (inclusive).

    Example:
        >>> items = [0, 46, 98, "1", "2", "798", "yuyuy", "nm"]
        >>> get_items_between_indexes(items, "2", "y")
        ["2", "798", "yuyuy"]
    """
    # if type(startAt) is int and type(endAt) is int:
    start_index = next(
        (i for i, item in enumerate(items) if str(item).startswith(startAt)), None
    )
    end_index = next(
        (i for i, item in enumerate(items) if str(item).startswith(endAt)), None
    )
    # else:
    #     start_index = next(
    #         (i for i, item in enumerate(items) if str(item).startswith(startAt)), None
    #     )
    #     end_index = next(
    #         (i for i, item in enumerate(items) if str(item).startswith(endAt)), None
    #     )

    if start_index is None or end_index is None:
        return []

    if start_index > end_index:
        start_index, end_index = end_index, start_index

    return items[start_index : end_index + 1]
```

Here's what I expect:

Example:

```bash
>>> items = [0, 2, 46, 64, 98, 181, 7898, "1", "2", "798", "nm", "yuyuy"]
>>> get_items_between_indexes(items, "2", "n")
["2", "798", "nm"]
>>> items = [0, 2, 46, 64, 98, 181, 657, 7898, "1", "2", "798", "nm"]
>>> get_items_between_indexes(items, 46, 1000)
[46, 64, 98, 181, 657]
```

Comment: `"n" < "nm"`, but in your example it seems as if you want to act as if `"n" == "nm"`.  How does this translate to the int values?  What if there are multiple values that all start with the same letter/digit?

Comment: Then the `start_index` will be the smallest, and the `end_index` will be the largest. We also follow the standard sorting chronology where letters and digits are sorted in a specific manner.

Comment: You may use `itertools.dropwhile()` to find the related start item

Comment: Can you share your implementation for the above use-case? And how would find the last item?

Comment: Can you have mixed parameters like `get_items_between_indexes(items, 100, "8")`?

Comment: Yeah, we can have that... but there may come unexpected edge cases with those. I have thought about implementing a regex expression that matches strings up to the first character, and we generate a pattern based upon the `startAt` & `endAt` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

#### Implementation

Here's the solution to the above question...

- We will use the arguments to form a pattern
- Match and search the list strings only up to the first character

```
import re

def get_items_between_range(
    items: List[str], startAt: Union[str, int], endAt: Union[str, int]
) -> List[str]:
    if len(startAt) > 1:
        startAt = str(startAt).lower()[1]
    else:
        startAt = str(startAt).lower()

    if len(endAt) > 1:
        endAt = str(endAt).lower()[1]
    else:
        endAt = str(endAt).lower()

    pattern = f"^[{startAt}-{endAt}]"+"{1}"
    items = (item for i, item in enumerate(items) if re.search(pattern, item, re.IGNORECASE))
    return list(items)
```

#### Example Usage

```py
l2 = ["aqi", "cars", "dosage", "dummy", "maze", "quiz", "sample", "trips", "users", "zoo"]
get_items_between_range(l2, "d", "u")
>> ['dosage', 'dummy', 'maze', 'quiz', 'sample', 'trips', 'users']
```